# How to tell if my MacBook Air supports USB 3.0

Tags: macos, usb, macbook, usb-3

How do I tell if my MacBook Air supports USB 3.0.  I found

**About This Mac** → **More Info...** → **System Report...** → **Hardware** → **USB**

But nothing there clearly states version 2.0 or 3.0.  How can I know for sure?  In particular, I want to know if I can use an external hard drive that requires a "USB 3.0-ready laptop".

[image]

Comment: genral thing According to apple's website, the Macbook Pro is only USB 2.0 http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/

Comment: @Vignesh4303 According to those page, Macbook Pro (current version) has 2 x USB 3.0. (And according to this page -> http://www.apple.com/macbook-air/specs.html) Macbook Air has 2 x USB 3.0 as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

USB 3.0 often has blue lining inside the port.

If you want to know specifically for your macbook air, go to apple support page http://support.apple.com/specs/ - Click on "Browse by Product" and enter your Macbook Air serial number. It will show you the Tech Spec specifically for your Macbook Air series, and the tech spec will tell you what USB you have.

Comment: Thanks!  I've read the "blue lining" is not necessarily the case with Macs, but the Tech Spec page you linked to gave me a clear answer.

Comment: at the time of this comment, the search does not work on serial number on apple support ...

Answer (score 9):

You were looking in the right place, it does tell you there. Take a look at the highlighted part in my screenshot below.

[image]

A USB Hi-Speed bus is USB 2.0, A USB 'SuperSpeed' or USB '3.0 Hi-Speed' bus are both USB3.

Comment: Mine doesn't have those two lines you highlighted.  Also, it's confusing, you say a USB Hi-Speed bus is USB 2.0, but in the image highlighted it says USB 3.0 Hi-Speed Bus (in addition to USB 3.0 SuperSpeed Bus).

Comment: If you read the line underneath the image it explains what to look for. The key thing is that a USB3 bus *will* have the 'USB 3.0' part in the line somewhere.

Comment: My bad, sorry I missed that, it's late.

Answer (score 1):

Tap the black apple, then choose "About this Mac, followed by Support, then Specifications. Lots of info there, including number and type of USB port

Comment: Does this give you different information than the route specified in the question: About This Mac → More Info... → System Report... → Hardware → USB?

Answer (score 1):

(just updating an old question)

To cover all Mac's and the technology in general, USB 3.0 adds 5 pins and unique interfaces. Where the shape hasn't changed (like with type "A", the flat plain rectangle), just look for the extra 5 pads or contacts.

This should produce a positive ID across computers more reliably than manufacturer labeling, color preferences, or document accuracy.

[This page](http://www.moddiy.com/pages/USB-2.0-%7B47%7D-3.0-Connectors-%26-Pinouts.html) has a nice set of comparison images. There are also a few singles down the right side of the [Wikipedia USB 3.0 article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, there are 3 things that confirm that you have only USB2:

1. USB High-Speed Bus
2. Driver: EHCI
3. Speed: 480Mb/s

> ```
> USB 1.0   Low Speed (1.5 Mbit/s), Full Speed (12 Mbit/s)
> USB 2.0   High Speed (480 Mbit/s)     
> USB 3.0   SuperSpeed (5 Gbit/s)
> USB 3.1   SuperSpeed+ (10 Gbit/s)
> ```

**Reference:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB

> #### Open Host Controller Interface
>
> The OHCI standard for USB is similar to the **OHCI** standard for
> FireWire, but supports USB 1.1 (full and low speeds) only.
>
> #### Universal Host Controller Interface
>
> Universal Host Controller Interface (**UHCI**) is a proprietary
> interface created by Intel for USB 1.x (full and low speeds).
>
> #### Enhanced Host Controller Interface
>
> Enhanced Host Controller Interface (**EHCI**-SPECIFICATION) is a
> high-speed controller standard applicable to USB 2.0.
>
> #### Extensible Host Controller Interface
>
> Extensible Host Controller Interface (**XHCI**) is the newest host
> controller standard that improves speed, power efficiency and
> virtualization over its predecessors The goal was also to define a USB
> host controller to replace UHCI/OHCI/EHCI. It supports all USB device
> speeds (USB 3.1 SuperSpeed+, USB 3.0 SuperSpeed, USB 2.0 Low-, Full-,
> and High-speed, USB 1.1 Low- and Full-speed).

**Reference:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_controller_interface_(USB,_Firewire)